# Dynamics of a future option

Tags: stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

I have trouble understanding why $$V_s = \exp\left(\int_t^s r_u\;du\right) \int_t^s \exp\left(-\int_t^v r_u\;du\right) \theta_v dW_v$$ solves the SDE 
$$dV_S = \theta_s dW_s + r_sV_sds$$
I tried using Ito's Lemma but I do not really know what function $f$ I should use.

Comment: Try $V_s=A_sC_s$ with $A_s=\exp\big(\int_t^s r_u\;du\big)$ and $C_s=\int_t^s A_v^{-1} \theta_v dW_v$ hence $dA_s=\ldots$, $dC_s=\ldots$ and $dV_s=\ldots$